# Dictionary key from object field

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to use an object as a key in a dictionary, but I want to lose the identity of the key to that of one of the object's fields. Overloading the hash and equality functions is trivial, and works as expected, but I was not able to find a solution for the key to be inserted with the field's type inside the dictionary.

Here is an example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.val == other.val
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            return self.val == other
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.val)

# this is false
print Foo(3) == Foo(4)

# this is true
print Foo(3) == Foo(3)

# this is true
print Foo(3) == 3
```

Now, if I use a Foo instance as a key, the identity of the key is a Foo instance (as expected):

```
d = {}
d[Foo(3)] = 'bar'

>>> print(d)
{<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fe47b8e0a70>: 'bar'}
```

What I would like is `d[Foo(3)]` to actually exchange the key for the int type `3` such that there is no trace of the Foo class inside the dictionary:

```
d = {}
d[Foo(3)] = 'bar'

>>> print(d)
{3: 'bar'}
```

Edit 1: as a clarification, note that I do not care about the behavior of the print statement, what I want is, as someone put it below, my "Foo" instance to automagically become an "int" when used as a key.

Edit 2: In my case the field is a string and the dictionary eventually gets dumped to a json file, which can only take string and scalar types. I do not want to have to explicitly cast my object to string since it *is* a string.

Edit 3: Unfortunately, it looks like what I'm after has already been proposed (and rejected): [PEP-455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/)

Comment: Uuuum `d[Foo(3).val] = 'bar'`?

Comment: Do you want a `Foo` instance to automagically become an `int` when used as a key? Or do you just want to change the output given by `print`?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Exactly, I want the Foo instance to automagically become an int when used as a key. I will clarify my question.

Comment: That's not possible unless you can customize your dict. However, try to add more context to your question: maybe there exists a better approach that you have not considered

Comment: You might want to read [PEP-455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/), which was rejected.

Comment: @chepner thanks, that's exactly what I needed (and will not be able to do). I will do as I was doing before (which is exactly what RickyA wrote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit is better than implicit.<sup>1</sup> In this case, it means using an integer as the key rather than expecting an object to "become" an integer in this context.

Take RickyA's advice.

```
d[Foo(3).val] = 'bar'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Second item in the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Comment: I will accept this answer, as this is what I was already doing, and it seems like there is no better solution.